# Vuejs has a limitation when add dynamicaly data

Tags: vue.js

I know how I can add a member to the data dynamically base on this documentation :

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

but there is a problem.
When you add a simple member Vue can track property changes :

var vm = new Vue({
data: {
a: 1
}
})

Vue.set(vm.someObject, 'b', 2);

this is right and the binding is perfect but when you try add a complex object Vue can not track changes:

Vue.set(vm.someObject, 'b', {"A":"Test"});

Is it a bug or limitation? Or there is a solution for doing this?

Comment: Are you sure: http://jsfiddle.net/deepaksingh/vjvMp/1406/

Comment: Just a note, you are right this is ok, but in my scenario Vue.set called inside a component that dynamically loaded....

Comment: By the way: when you define a component template vue automatically removes the script section. I change the vue for this. my vue version now do not remove script section.